# AWS DMS : Replication task has stopped. Stop Reason FULL_LOAD_ONLY_FINISHED

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-dms, dms

Facing issues like stopped replication in DMS.

[events error DMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFap9.png)

ANyone any idea how to resolve this.

aws lambda log snapshot,

[lambda-logs-entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgAU6.png)

Doing MySQL to Postgres migration

source: rds MySQL

Destination: aurora postgres

Answer (score 0):

This request is closed now.

I have upgraded the DMS instance size and changes in parameter group in RDS MySQL.

Thx.